# Rails app with mongoid ... (Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig): No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

With reference to https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2894#issuecomment-14903927 
I've done all the necessary changes ... still the issue is there ...

spec_helper.rb file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", FILE)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'rails/mongoid'
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.14.0'
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

mongoid.yml

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongo_demo_development
    hosts:
      - localhost:27017
    options:        
 options:

test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongo_demo_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong      
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Following is the Error Log which is generated when I run my rails server with $rails s ...

```
/home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:27:in create': (Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig)
Problem:
No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:137:inwith_name'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:390:in __session__'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:227:inmongo_session'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:171:in collection'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:265:ininitialize'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:51:in new'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:51:increate_context'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:34:in context'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18:inlast'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/mongoid-d52c33bce36a/lib/mongoid/findable.rb:130:in last'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/app/rules/myrule_book.rb:5:inclass:Myrule_Book'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/app/rules/myrule_book.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:inload'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in block in load_file'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:innew_constants_in'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in load_file'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:inrequire_or_load'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in load_missing_constant'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:inconst_missing'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config/environments/development.rb:30:in block in <top (required)>'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:inclass_eval'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in configure'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config/environments/development.rb:1:in'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in require'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:inblock in require'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in load_dependency'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:inrequire'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:ineach'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inblock in run_initializers'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in block in tsort_each'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:inblock (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:210:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:ineach_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:209:in block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:ineach'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in tsort_each_child'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:203:ineach_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:ineach'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:intsort_each'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in run_initializers'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:ininitialize!'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in method_missing'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config/environment.rb:5:in'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config.ru:3:in require'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config.ru:3:inblock in '
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:ininitialize'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config.ru:in new'
from /home/nikunj/Practice/mongo_demo/config.ru:in'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:innew_from_string'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:inbuild_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in app'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:inapp'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in wrapped_app'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:instart'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in block in <top (required)>'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:intap'
from /home/nikunj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in <top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:inrequire'
from bin/rails:4:in `'
```

Comment: Hi,Rails.env = 'test' and check once again

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: are you trying to load a gem from local in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Your mongoid.yml has an error "hosts:" key should be inside of "default:" because it is a required configuration for sessions

Please check http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and error message - In my case it was caused because the yml config file wasn't loaded. I added the following line

```
 Mongoid.load!('config/mongoid.yml')
```

to config/application.rb and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

may be The problem is in the gem file, you did't mention the version of mongoid gem. in gem file change  `gem "mongoid"` to `gem "mongoid" , '~> 4.0.2'` and run bundle install restart server and console.